# LinkedIn Traffic Issue

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I have implemented login with LinkedIn. I am getting following error while accessing LinkedIn API's.

"Request denied

Sorry, we are unable to serve your request at this time due to unusual traffic from your network connection. "

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: you might wanna check the params you are sending to them. you might be missing someting or sending something extra

Comment: Thanks for your response. But It was working on some other server. Now I moved the site to new server. And I am getting this problem. For getting the data in my old server I have used file_get_contents function. But as this new server does not support it, I am using curl to get data.